During the execution of main.py, i want to execute a function from DSD.py and need to get variables from main.py but error occurred

AttributeError: partially initialized module 'Display_SQL_Database' has no attribute 'data_writes' (most likely due to a circular import)

If anyone gets a solution please provide a brief description of the problem, why it was occurred
